# Delphi: Migrate DBMS

Tags: database, delphi, migrate

I've got a Delphi 2010 app that uses DBISAM and a client who wants it in SQL Server. I *think* I can migrate the data into SQL Server relatively easily, but I think I then have to change all the `TDBISAMTable` and `TDBISAMQuery` to `TSQLTable` and `TSQLQuery` (manually).

It's all in a data module so I think my best bet is to basically re-add all the components (and from there the field defs can be auto-generated, as I recall).

Do I have this right or is there an easier way to switch DBMSes?

Comment: Which Delphi version?

Comment: I edited the question to include that.

Comment: D2010?  That's too early for Delphi's current db-access offering. FireDAC, but as its developer left EMBA a while ago and they've had a lot of lay-offs, you might be wise to regard that as an evolutionary dead end.  For Sql Server, try accessing your converted tables via Delphi's ADO components, TAdoQuery in particular and make sure you use client-side cursors.

Comment: Thanks, MartynA. I think that means that I have to re-do my entire data module, correct?

Comment: Not necessarily, depends on what your dm contains.  The datasets will need to be replaced obviously, but code whicj operates on them should be pretty much the same.

Comment: Yeah, I meant the components. I'm hoping the rest of it will work pretty transparently.